# getLayoutParams() from LinearLayout return null

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, bottom-sheet

I want to implement a BottomSheetBehavoir component to an activity screen, but when I want to initialize the component via `BottomSheetBehavoir.from(view)` the **getLayoutParams()** method throw a null pointer exception.

This is my init code in onCreate():

```
LinearLayout llBottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_live_tracking_list_container);
BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(llBottomSheet);
```

And this is my xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_live_tracking_list_container"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white"
app:behavior_hideable="false"
app:behavior_peekHeight="40dp"
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_gray">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/show_more"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/activity_live_tracking_show_more_tv" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_filter_list"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/activity_live_tracking_position_list_rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I include this layout in my root xml layout via the include tag.

Error code:

```
2020-02-21 12:34:05.097 8419-8419/de.app.haveltec.ilockit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: de.app.haveltec.ilockit, PID: 8419
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.app.haveltec.ilockit/de.app.haveltec.ilockit.screens.livetracking.LiveTrackingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1839)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6861)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference
    at com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior.from(BottomSheetBehavior.java:981)
    at de.app.haveltec.ilockit.screens.livetracking.LiveTrackingActivity.onCreate(LiveTrackingActivity.java:147)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7232)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7221)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2964)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1839) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6861) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Comment: can you please add error log?

Comment: is your `bottom_sheet_live_tracking_list_container` is child of `CoordinatorLayout`?

Comment: Yes it is, the bottom sheet works fine when I run the App without the initializing it in my activity

Comment: which version you are using of `com.android.support:design`?

Comment: I use android x migration or do I also have to set the design library when I use android x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after I rest some days and go back to the problem I found the solution. For my LinearLayout, that throws the getLayoutParams() null pointer exception, I use the id from the bottom sheet xml that you can see in my post `android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_live_tracking_list_container"`. In my main layout there the parent is a CoordinatorLayout is include my bottom sheet layout like this:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

... other stuff ....

<include
    android:id="@+id/activity_live_tracking_bottom_sheet"
    layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_live_tracking_list" />
```

Know I try the id from the include tag (`android:id="@+id/activity_live_tracking_bottom_sheet"`) and it works. I can't give you an explanation why the other id that marked the LinearLayout directly returning null for getLayoutParams() method.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior) BottomSheetBehaviour is **deprecated**. If you still want to use it, make sure it is child of a CoordinatorLayout as that is a prerequisite to use it according to the doc.
Would rather have added this answer as a comment, but not enough reputation...

Comment: BottomSheetBehaviour is not marked as deprecated in AndroidStudio for me and it is a child of CoordinatorLayout

Comment: just method setBottSheetBehavios ist depricated [see here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetBehavior#setbottomsheetcallback) . So use addBottomSheetCallback(BottomSheetCallback) instead

Comment: My app crashed because getLayoutParams() from the LinearLayout child is null, this has nothing todo with the callback listener